# Use of proper interceptor logic in Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have a products.impex file with an attribute gender=MALE or FEMALE in the itemtype MyProduct(which extends Product) I have an attribute "choice" which depends on the values in the gender column so I initially wrote a PrepareInterceptor and checked for isNew condition.Now it works fine for the new rows but when the value is changed it does not work.Should I just remove the isNew condition or use InitDefaultsInterceptor?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (ctx.isRemoved(productModel))
{
    //TODO
}
else if (ctx.isNew(productModel) || ctx.isModified(productModel, ProductModel.GENDER))
{
    //TODO
}
```

As far as interceptor concern, you can use **PrepareInterceptor** for preparing fields value as it called before **ValidateInterceptor**. If you just want to validate your fields then use **ValidateInterceptor**. The Init Defaults Interceptor is called when a model is filled with its default values.

Have a look at [interceptor life cycle](https://help.hybris.com/6.7.0/hcd/8bfbf43e8669101480d0f060d79b1baa.html).